# Execute sp_setnetname by non admin user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to change ip of linked server. I use procedure `sp_setnetname` for it.
I have login `user1` with `public` server role. 
Try run such code:

```
    EXECUTE AS USER = 'user2';
    EXEC ('sp_setnetname ''LinkedServerName'', ''' + 'SomeIp' + '''')
    REVERT;
```

where `user2` has `sysadmin` server role. But I receive error:

`Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "user2" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.`

Help me to resolve this error or find any other way to change ip for linked server by non admin user.

Comment: Do you mean `LOGIN`? A `USER` can't have the `sysadmin` role as a `USER` is a database object. `sysadmin` is a Server role that can be given to a `LOGIN`; it can't be given to a database `USER`.

Comment: This approach is doomed to failure -- if a user has no permission to run `sp_setnetname` they also won't (or definitely should not) have permission to impersonate a user that does at will. You can use a stored procedure that uses `EXECUTE AS` and grant permission to execute that.

Comment: @larnu, login `user1` is mapped to user `user1`, and login 'user2' is mapped to user 'user2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolve my problem such way:

1. Login User1 has still public server role.
2. Login User1 is still mapped to database user User1.
3. Add for login User1 permission `Alter any linked server`.

I hope it is help for somebody such I.

P.S. Thanks @Jeroen Mostert for idea.